# How do I continue if response time is more than 0.5 sec?

Tags: node.js, callback, sleep

```
var request = require('request'), async = require('async');
var opt=["http://localhost:8080/examples/jsp/abc.jsp","http://192.168.24.180:8080/examples/jsp/abc.jsp"];
function req()
{
    var count = 0;
    async.eachSeries(opt, function(entry, callback)
    {
        count++;
        request(entry, function(error, response, body)
        {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
            {
                console.log('Yes ' + entry);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('No '+entry);
            }
            callback(); 
        });
    }, function(err)
    {
        console.log('Continue');
    });
}
req();
```

How do I get it to show "No" if response time is more than .5 sec. The files on the server have a random sleep time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using https://github.com/mikeal/request?

If so, according to http://www.sitepoint.com/making-http-requests-in-node-js/ you can pass in an object to entry [request(entry, function(err] instead of just a URL and include in that.

From the sitepoint link

```
request({
  uri: "http://www.sitepoint.com",
  method: "GET",

  timeout: 10000, <- that's what you looking for

  followRedirect: true,
  maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: so, 10000 means .5 sec?

Comment: no, from the link 

"timeout parameter tells request to wait 10,000 milliseconds (ten seconds)"

So 0.5 seconds in milliseconds would be 500

Comment: Units would be in millihalfseconds (mhs) :D. This and a different error handling for `ETIMEDOUT` will do the trick.

Comment: When I use the timeout it is included for the entire async call and not initialized after every call - @brent

Comment: Could you update your question to include the code you are now using? I don't understand the difference between "entire async call" vs "every call"